# Bibtex apacite puts all title entries in italics except the one in @article

Tags: bibtex, formatting, apacite

I use the `apacite` bibliography style and the `apacite` package for my thesis. I have one issue. All titles are put in italics excepts the ones in entries of type `@article`. In this entry type, it puts the journal name in italics, which I do not want.

This is my preamble.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm, left=3.5cm,top=24.5mm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx,booktabs}
\usepackage{lmodern,textcomp} %euro symbol package
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} %interline 1.5 cm
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\graphicspath{{Images//}}
\usepackage{rotating}%voor rotatie tables
\usepackage{adjustbox}%aanpassen tabel afmetingen
\usepackage{lmodern,textcomp} %eurosymbool
\usepackage{tabularx}
```

The document

```
\begin{document}
\cite{alexandersson_swedish_2008}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{Library}
\end{document}
```

One of my entries in the library

```
@article{alexandersson_swedish_2008,
title = {The {Swedish} railway deregulation path},
author = {Alexandersson, G. and Hulten, S.},
year = {2008},
journal = {Review of Network Economics},
volume = {7},
number = {1},
pages = {1-19},
file = {The_Swedish_Railway_Deregulation_Path.pdf:C\:\\Users\\loren\\Zotero\\storage\\35TRNFGG\\The_Swedish_Railway_Deregulation_Path.pdf:application/pdf}
```

}

My references. The first four are articles. The others are another entry and so have the title in italics.

[image]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What happens if you do not use the hyperref package?

Answer (score 1):

Just so that this has an answer that works, and does NOT involve putting formatting into the `.bib` file (which you should almost never do), the `apacite` package has some hooks to facilitate the formatting of certain elements.  In this case the relevant macro to redefine is:

```
\APACrefatitle
```

we can redefine it in the following way:

```
\renewcommand{\APACrefatitle}[1]{\emph{#1}.}
```

This will make article titles italic.

Doing this, however, makes article titles and the corresponding journal title formatted the same way, which is really not a good idea. If you want to preserve a difference between the two, you could also redefine the journal title to be upright, using:

```
\renewcommand{\APACjournalVolNumPages}[4]{{#1 }{#2}{(#3), }{#4}}
```

**Disclaimer**

Note that this is **extremely** non-standard and you shouldn't do it. Not only does it not conform to the APA style, it doesn't conform to any other style I am aware of.

Answer (score -1):

I asked at the department and they told me that how it was done by latex was the correct way. It was not clearly stated in the document that handled the bibliography settings.

However, there is a way to change the bibliography in the way I described. This is done by going to the `.bib` file and add `\textit{Title}` to the entry of the title file. To put journal in plain straight style you add `\emph{Name journal}` to the journal entry.

Not the most beautiful solution but it works.

Comment: You are free to disagree with the stylistic settings of any particular bibliography style. But the advice you're dispensing is highly questionable. The `apacite` bibliography style implements the style requirements laid out in the 6th edition of the APA manual. If you can't stand some of these settings, your main reaction should be to start searching for a more agreeable bibliography style. For sure, if you are required to use the `apacite` bibliography style and, presumably, the `apacite` package, you should under no circumstance change `Journal Name` to `\emph{Journal Name}` in the bib file.